# Why is there an "as" in "L'hôtel as deux étages"?

Tags: grammaire

When translating "The hotel has", wouldn't we be using the "il a" conjugation of avoir, so why is it that the "tu as" form is being used here? I thought it was supposed to be "L'hôtel a deux étages".

Comment: The correct sentence is "L'hôtel a deux étages." The "as" is wrong here.

Comment: State in your question what is the "here" you are mentioning (give context), because your "here" is obviously **not** a reliable source. [This is](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/The%20hotel%20has%20two%20floors.)  a more reliable source.

Comment: I checked the reasons for closing; "off topic" is what has been chosen. This question is not off topic. It's a perfectly valid question from someone who does not have enough experience yet to assert that there is no other possibility than that of an error. It is just a simple question, but only provided you know a lot about the language.

Comment: I was doing a Duolingo lesson and they wrote it as "L'hôtel as deux étages". Guess they were wrong.

Comment: They were! Congratulations for spotting the mistake, keep the good work :).